# Nested enum in Struct, Swift compiler error?

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I can't define `employee( x:empsex , y:approval )`, types are not available.

Trying to use nested enums with struct.

```
public struct Employee {
public var empsex   : Gender
public var approval : Eligible


public enum Gender : String{
    case male = "MALE"
    case female = "FEMALE"
    public static var genderARR = ["MALE","FEMALE"]
}
public enum Eligible : Int {
    case x = 1 //yes
    case y = 0 //no
    public static var eligibleARR = [1,0]
}
}

public struct Strofempoyestu {
public var empdata : [Employee]=[]


public init (){
    for x in Employee.Gender.genderARR{
        for y in Eemployee.Eligible.eligibleARR{
            empdata.append(Employee( x:empsex , y:approval ))

        }

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that you declared `genderARR` as `String` instead of `Gender` and `eligibleARR` as `Int` instead of `Eligible`.

```
public struct Employee {
    public var empsex   : Gender
    public var approval : Eligible

    public enum Gender : String{
        case male = "MALE"
        case female = "FEMALE"
        public static var genderARR = [male,female]
    }
    public enum Eligible : Int {
        case x = 1 //yes
        case y = 0 //no
        public static var eligibleARR = [x,y]
    }
}

public struct Strofempoyestu {
    public var empdata : [Employee]=[]

    public init (){
        for x in Employee.Gender.genderARR{
            for y in Employee.Eligible.eligibleARR{
                empdata.append(Employee(empsex: x ,approval: y))
            }
        }
    }
}
```